# Is there a weather widget/app that has both very good location support and supports multiple locations?

Tags: htc-desire-hd, weather

Is there a weather widget or app that has good location support (Central Europe) and support for multiple configured locations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WeatherBug](http://www.appbrain.com/app/weatherbug/com.aws.android) (free) seems to meet your criteria.  Has nice widgets, multiple location support, and tons of weather stations.

There is also a pay version ([WeatherBug Elite](http://www.appbrain.com/app/weatherbug-elite/com.aws.android.elite)) which removes ads and adds several additional features such as radar in motion and detailed hourly forecasts.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [The Weather Channel](http://www.appbrain.com/app/the-weather-channel/com.weather.Weather#) official app - which some users claim is more accurate than WeatherBug. Try both and see which suits you better.

[image: Weather Channel App]

Comment: This app requires calling permissions, I'm not installing that.